# How do I set defined decimal values in Lua?

Tags: lua

I can not find solution for solving this problem. I would like to let user set exact number of decimal places like this:

```
print("Enter number of decimal places:")
dec = io.read("*number")

decnum = string.format("%.decf, somenumber);
print(decnum)
```

Is there any way how I can pass dec value into string.format or is there better solution?

Comment: `string.format('%.'..dec..'f', somenumber);`

Comment: thank you, it works